# Where did all entries to ILogger go?

Tags: azure-functions

It's a recent change in portal.azure.com, I can't seem to find my functions (core 3.1) logs anymore? The ones that is outputted by ILogger. Before I could go into functions and view executions and see the logs produced by using ILogger. I don't find it anymore, did they move it?

Comment: Did you check Functions -> _Function name_ -> Monitor?

Comment: I have post an answer, please let me know whether you solved the problem after you try that. If you face some problem, please let me know.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, the function must configure the corresponding application insights before you can view the log on the portal.

So you need to configure an application insights to your function app like this:

[image]

Then your function app will restart.

Of course, you can also go to kudu to view:

First, go to advanced tools, then click 'GO',

[image]

Then After you go to kudu, click Debug Console -> CMD -> LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> yourtriggername. You will find log file there.

If you are based on linux OS, after go to kudu, just click log stream is ok.